# pgpool for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Is there something like [pgpool](http://pgpool.projects.postgresql.org/pgpool-II/doc/pgpool-en.html) for MySQL?

It seems like there ought to be, and it'd be tremendously useful, but I've never heard of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [MySQL_Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy)?

Comment: That looks pretty nice.  I'm most interested in the parallel query feature, and it's not clear if/how MySQL Proxy supports that, but it's certainly worth a look!